# Input and output array don't match

Tags: c, arrays, printing, output

I am writing a program for a class at school and I cannot get the program to print out what I type in.

The problem states that the first line needs to contain the number of questions on an 'exam' followed by a space then the answer key.  I wanted to print the answer key to make sure that it was being entered in correctly and it never matches what I type in.  The code is posted below.

This is the main file that starts being run and it calls a method from another file I have made the prototype file correctly so I'm pretty sure it's not that.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int noOfQuestions;
    scanf("%d ", &noOfQuestions);
    char * answerKeyPtr;

    answerKeyPtr = fgetAnswers(noOfQuestions);

    for(i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++){
        printf("%c",answerKeyPtr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

char *fgetAnswers(int noOfQuestions){
    int i;
    char * answerKeyPtr;
    char AnswerKey[noOfQuestions];
    answerKeyPtr = AnswerKey;

    for(i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++){
        scanf("%c",&AnswerKey[i]);
    }

    return answerKeyPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a memory problem.

You're storing data into the `AnswerKey` array, which is local to `fgetAnswers()`. The problem is you're returning a pointer to that local variable, and that variable's memory is not reliable as soon as your fgetAnswers() function finishes that memory should not be accessed. So when you try to print the data in `main()` you're accessing memory you shouldn't.

To solve it, create the `AnswersKey` array in main, and pass it as a parameter to the `fgetAnswers()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The char array `AnswerKey` is allocated on the stack when `fgetAnswers` is called. When you return from `fgetAnswers`, data stored in the stack frame for that call is no longer valid. You'll need to pass in the array or alloc it so the input isn't stored in the stack.

Comment: so I added `char answerKey[noOfQuestions];`  to the beginning of the main function and `answerKeyPtr = &answerKey[0];`  a couple lines later.  Is that what you were talking about? I still get somewhat confused with pointers

Comment: You still have a problem. Until you have a value for noOfQuestions, you can't allocate the array using char answerKey[noOfQuestions]. You should alloc space after reading in the number of questions. You could also define a MAXQUESTIONS constant and declare the array to be that size, then make sure the number read in is <= MAXQUESTIONS. I'd recommend using alloc, because you need to get comfortable with pointers.

Comment: After you allocate the array to hold the answers, pass it to your fgetAnswers function. fgetAnswers(int noOfQustions, char *questionBuffer)  Alternatively, allocate the space for the character array inside the function using alloc(). That would be safe to return. A little later, you should learn how to use free() to release the alloc()-ed space when you are done with it.